# Rearrange homescreens on Pixel 5, Android 12

Tags: home-screen, google-pixel, android-12

I want to rearrange my homescreens on Google Pixel 5, Android 12 stock, Pixel Launcher. Since Android P, it is not possible anymore to rearrange homescreens with vanilla launcher:

- [Google has removed the option to reorder homescreens on Android P's default launchers](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/07/18/google-removed-option-reorder-homescreens-android-ps-default-launchers/)
- [[Developer Preview Android P] ability to re-order home screens has been removed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111287281?pli=1%22)

I tried searching for alternative launchers to use temporarily to switch them back but without luck. The same goes for searching apps that have an app organizing feature.

Is there a way in which I rearrange my apps and home screens easily for Pixel Launcher? Otherwise, do apps on unrooted devices have the privileges of changing app orders?

Comment: The launcher app is just an app which means it is also sandboxed from other apps which makes it impossiblem to access or modify from outside (unless it explicitly provides an interface for that). Therefore my suggestion would be to search for an alternative launcher that suits your needs and then permanently switch to it.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, a Q&A site for end-users solving their issues. Note that our focus is not on Android developers, which our sister site [so] has covered most of the topics, so we can't provide suggestions on how to create such an app. Also, please note that asking only for apps is generally off-topic, I'll make some adjustments to the question to make it still on-scope on here, but feel free to [edit] and improve if I miss something.

Comment: That said, the articles are talking about homescreens on Google's Pixel (Pixel Launcher) and AOSP (Launcher3). But as Robert said, that doesn't mean other Launcher apps are affected. However, it also means that Pixel Launcher doesn't have this feature in-built. Perhaps there's a hackable workaround (e.g. editing the DB/preference file directly on rooted devices) though.

Comment: try microsoft launcher. i guess it got the feature you need.

Comment: @Robert interesting thing with the sandbox, i didn't know that. Alright then. I basically just rearranged verything from scratch, by clearing cache / data from pixel launcher which was kinda ok speedwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a workaround. Basically deleting my current setup and then setting it up from scratch. Deleting works by clearing data of the pixel launcher app.
It's at least a bit faster to start from scratch without rearranging and takes just 5 to 10 min

Thank you for your Comments and your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is a little dated, but I landed on it today, trying to figure out the same thing.

I see one suggestion for an alternate launcher, but I have chosen to use Nova Launcher instead of the Pixel Launcher.

[Nova Launcher in Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en_US&gl=US)

Nova Launcher is extremely customizable and can be made to look identical to the Pixel Launcher layout. Additionally, it allows you to combine several apps into a group, saving space when you have several apps with nearly the same functionality.

You can shuffle pages, change which one is the home screen, change the animation between pages, change the shape, size, and grid size of icons, select alternate icon packs, etc

Beyond that, Nova Launcher has a significant number of options that can satisfy your needs for customizing your Android look, functionality, and even custom gestures.

You can even make a backup of your configuration, layout, and icon positions, so if something drastic happens, at least you don't have to start all over from scratch.

Should someone happen on this question, looking to solve the same problem, I wouldn't want them to miss out on the option to give Nova Launcher a try as an alternative option.

Comment: I too use Nova Launcher on my phones. It is excellent